# Evaluating an Integral Using Cauchy's Theorem and Root-Finding

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

I am tasked with evaluating the following integral utilizing the Cauchy theorem:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(2 - \cos t)^{2}}dt$$

I have initiated my calculation as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(2 - \cos t)^{2}}dt &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{4-2\cos t + (\cos t)^{2}}dt \\&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{4 - 2\cdot\frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2} + \frac{(e^{it} + e^{-it})^{2}}{4}}\\&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{4\cdot dt}{16 - 4e^{it} - 4e^{-it} + e^{2it}+ 2e^{0} + e^{-2it}} \\&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{4e^{it}}{18e^{it} - 4e^{2it} - 4 + e^{3it} + e^{-it}} \cdot \frac{d(e^{it})}{i \cdot e^{it}}\\&= \frac{4}{i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d(e^{it})}{18e^{it} - 4e^{2it} - 4 + e^{3it} + e^{-it}} \\&= \frac{4}{i} \oint \frac{dz}{18z - 4z^{2} + z^{3} + z^{-1} - 4}
\end{align*}$$

To advance to the next stage of the calculations, I must determine the roots of the equation  $18z - 4z^{2} + z^{3} + z^{-3} - 4 = 0$

Unfortunately, I'm uncertain about the method to find these roots. It's possible that I'm overlooking a crucial step, and there might be an alternative approach to simplify the equation and make it more amenable to root-finding

Comment: it must be $z^{-1}$ instead of $z^{-3}$. Don't expand the square, as the square just duplicate the multiplicity of the roots of $2-\frac{z+\bar z}{2}$ inside the unit disk (if they exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z=e^{it}$ you have that $2-\cos t=2-\frac{z+\bar z}{2}=\frac{z^2-4z+1}{-2z}$ and $dt=\tfrac{dz}{iz}$, therefore

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{(2-\cos t)^2}=\oint \frac{4z^2}{(z^2-4z+1)^2}\cdot \frac{dz}{iz}=-4i\oint \frac{z\,d z}{(z-\alpha )^2(z-\beta )^2}
$$

for $\alpha =2-\sqrt{3}$ and $\beta =2+\sqrt{3}$. Now observe that $|\alpha |<1$ and $|\beta |>1$ so the unique pole on the unit disc of the integrand is at $\alpha $ with multiplicity two.